# Many to many resource mapping restful api design

Tags: rest, express, api-design, restful-url

There are many other questions here which target the same problem `many-to-many relationship url design for restful apis`. I have somewhat the same, *but it differs from other*.
I couldn't find any better approach. 
I have `locations` resource, and `services` resource`

```
GET /services                           //it should give you all services
GET /locations                          //it should give you all locations
GET /locations/:id/services             //it should give you all services offered by a location
```

The problem that I have is I have to design a route which gives 
*All locations along with services offered by them*
I went though a post on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9ail0l/how_do_you_designquery_your_backend_rest_api_for/) that suggests.
`GET /locations?include=services`


I also went through another [doc](https://github.com/NationalBankBelgium/REST-API-Design-Guide/wiki/REST-Resources-Many-to-many-Relations) . It suggest.
`GET  /locations-services`

I am sure I am not the first one who is having such confusion.
 Please help, and if possible share some resources which I can go through to clear my doubts off.

Comment: I think REST doesnt contemplate eager loading. This is more typical in graph services. I would go for `GET /locations?include=services` since it can scale. Maybe in the future you will need more eager resources: `GET /locations?include=services&population`

Comment: What will be the restful way to do the same. Is there any other way? The problem is i this approach. I have to do many if and code repetition for eager loading based on passed include.

Comment: Does expressjs treat `/locations` , `/locations?include=service` and `/locations?include=services&population` differently?

Comment: No. It will execute the same route. You only have to access the query string and check them in a single place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any spelling you want.  You should choose a spelling that is consistent with the spellings you use for other identifiers, for the same reason that we choose spellings of variable names that are consistent with other local variable names.

But

```
/a1dadfcb-8fc6-4456-b05e-a0b91575e0ef
```

is a perfectly satisfactory URI.

```
/locations?include=services
/locations?services
/locations-services
/locations/services
/service-directory
```

These are all *fine*.  General-purpose components don't care, so long as you use a spelling consistent with the production rules defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)

Comment: I would go with `/locations?include=services` makes more sense, and as @Rashomon suggested, if required I can do more includes.